# Expectation of integral of a stochastic process

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-integrals, stochastic-differential-equations

Let $r_t$ be governed by a mean reverting process:

$dr_t = K(\theta - r_t)dt + \sigma dW_t  $

where $W_t $ is standard weiner process, and $\sigma , K, \theta$ are constants

Can it be shown that $-log (E[e^{-\int r_sds}]) = \theta (T- \frac{(1- e^{-KT})}{K}) + r_o \frac{(1- e^{-KT})}{K}  $

Comment: A way to do that is first to show the solution for r is gaussian (check the web for Vasicek SDE). Once you have calculated the first 2 moments of this gaussian you are done as your expression is then the mean of a lognormal for random variable.

Comment: That's a good intuition! However, is there also an intuitive way tro suggest that r is in fact gaussian? Since it is a sum of non-iid normals, it need not be normal, right?

Answer (score 0):

This is the Ornstein-Uhlenbeck equation with general solution

$$x_t = x_0 e^{-K t}+\theta(1-e^{-K t}) + \tfrac{\sigma}{\sqrt{2K}} W_{1-e^{-2 K t}},$$

where $W_t$ is a Brownian motion. So then you are mainly asking to compute

$$E[exp(-\int^{t}  \tfrac{\sigma}{\sqrt{2K}} W_{1-e^{-2 K s}}ds)].$$

The integral is a random variable so we just have to compute its variance. By the "Theorem 8.5.7 (Time change formula for Itˆo integrals)" in Oksendal

$$\int^{a_{t}}v(s)dB_{s}=\int^{t}v(a_{r})\sqrt{a'_{r}}d\tilde{B}_{r}$$

we have

$$\int^{T}  W_{1-e^{-2 K t}}dt=\int^{T}\int^{1-e^{-2 K t}}\sqrt{2K}e^{-Kr}d\tilde{B}_{r}dt$$

and so by the Ito isometry

$$M_{T}:=E\left(\int^{T}  W_{1-e^{-2 K t}}dt\right)^{2}=E\left[\int^{T}\int^{T}\int^{1-e^{-2 K t_{1}}}\int^{1-e^{-2 K t_{2}}}2Ke^{-K(r_{1}+r_{2})}d\tilde{B}_{r_{1}}d\tilde{B}_{r_{2}}dt_{1}dt_{2}\right]$$

$$=\int^{T}\int^{T}\int^{\infty}\int^{\infty}\min(1-e^{-2 K t_{1}},1-e^{-2 K t_{2}})2Ke^{-K(r_{1}+r_{2})}dr_{1}dr_{2}dt_{1}dt_{2}.$$

Therefore, we get

$$E[exp(-\int^{t}  \tfrac{\sigma}{\sqrt{2K}} W_{1-e^{-2 K s}}ds)]=exp\left(\frac{M_{T}}{2}\tfrac{\sigma^{2}}{2K} \right).$$